# Count Up pic nr

Tags: regex, sed, count

i need to count up picture numbers in a lot of html-docs (in the img-tag):

```
<img src="../bilder/abb019.png" width="600" alt="Abb.19"/>
```

I tried to solve this with a regex (in sed) and also looked at some other languages (awk, php), but I didn't come up with a solution.
I can find the digits with a regex, but I can't count them up.
I can build a counter with a while loop (php), but I don't know how to apply it to the html files.
It's gotta be possible, I suppose. Which direction do I have to think? 
Pjoern

Comment: to count OR to sum up? If sum up - what numbers?

Comment: to count up - the numbers are part of the href-link and i want to serialize the numbering of the pictures for i dont want to do this manually.

Comment: post more context lines and post the final result

Comment: its just simple html, the result should be:
'img src="../bilder/abb019.png, img src="../bilder/abb020.png' 
and so on, with this snippets of course at different positions in the file

Comment: Could you post your attempts in sed/awk/php?

Comment: in php i found the common while loop: 
'<?php$i = 0;while($i < 10) {echo "$i, ";$i++;}?>'
but i can´t apply it to a larger html file
in sed i can serch a pattern like 'bilder\/abb\d{1,3}\/.png'
but i dont know how to increment the numer '\d{1,3}'
i think this number-pattern has to be replaced with a variable, but i didn´t found a solution